# Maven: Execute custom code during assembly

Tags: maven, custom-action, maven-assembly-plugin

We are using the assembly plugin to build a zip package.

I would like to execute some custom java code during the execution of the Maven Assembly plugin. The java app should have access to the structure of the assembly but **before** the zip file is built. So, files which should go into the zip might possibly be modified/added/removed.

How would I configure that?

Cheers

Jonas

Comment: If you like to the things you described you need to modify the maven-assembly-plugin. The question is what you like to achieve? May be you can elaborate a little bit more what you like to do?

Comment: In a nutshell I would like to include a _pom.xml_ file in the assembly containing all dependencies used in our project.

We use <dependencySet> to include all external jars separately in the package but I have not found a way to include a pom.

I thought I could generate that pom from the file names of our dependency jars.

Answer (score 2):

I do not think executing Java code is possible. Try getting along with exclusion patterns for file removal and maven filters for file modifications.

http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/advanced-descriptor-topics.html